# I am curently running ubuntu 16.04 on an acer chromebook 11 cb3-111-c670. and my sound does not work

Tags: drivers, sound, acer, chromebook

My audio controler is an Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller